# WCF webHttpBinding for both HTTP and HTTPS?

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding

I'm having a really hard time finding how to host a WCF service in an IIS site that works on both HTTP and HTTPS. I've done about 10 hours of research including just about every link on StackOverflow that relates to this issue and tried many different combinations and have not yet been able to get both working at the same time. Right now only HTTPS works with the below configuration:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <webHttpBinding>
            <binding name="http">
                <security mode="None">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" />
                </security>
            </binding>
            <binding name="https">
                <security mode="Transport">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </webHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="MyWcfServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior">
                <enableWebScript />
            </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true">
    </serviceHostingEnvironment>
    <services>
        <service name="MyWcfService">
            <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="MyWcfServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="http" contract="IMyWcfService" />
            <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="MyWcfServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="https" contract="IMyWcfService" />
        </service>
    </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to specify different endpoint "address" values in your service configuration.

For example:

```
<services>
    <service name="MyWcfService">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="MyWcfServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="http" contract="IMyWcfService" />
        <endpoint address="secure" behaviorConfiguration="MyWcfServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior" binding="webHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="https" contract="IMyWcfService" />
    </service>
</services>
```

Comment: So there's no way I can make the same URL work with both HTTP and HTTPS? I know for the address you have to append /servicename to your service URL.